# How to jump from an event handler in story board to the code

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a "Hello" button in the main view. I have set its Touch Up Inside handler to changeGreeting() in HelloWorldViewController.m. From the Connections Inspector, I can clear see this association:
[image]

My question is, how to jump to changeGreeting() function in the .m file from here (the story board view)?

I would expect simply clicking on that "Hello World View Controller changeGreeting:" button would bring me to the source code. But it turns out not the case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way (as far as I can tell) to jump directly from that panel to the `changeGreeting:` method.

You can press Command-Shift-O (or choose File > Open Quickly…) and type `changeGreeting:` (or some prefix of it) to jump to the definition.

If you want Apple to add a better way, go to https://bugreport.apple.com/ and file a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

You could go to the 'Jump Bar' which is the horizontal bar at the top of the main viewer. Here change the file to the .m file and then start typing 'change' or 'greeting' to see all the methods in this file that match the filter.